# c# instancia de clases duda

Tags: c#

```
introducir el código aquí

 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        myclass obj= new myclass
        {
            I = 1234,
            Ia = "string text"


        };
        Console.WriteLine(nuevo.Ia);// output "string text"
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
 class myclass
{
    private int i;
    private string ia;
    public myclass() { }


    public int I { get => i; set => i = value; }
    public string Ia { get => ia; set => ia = value; }
}
```

mi duda de como se llama y como funciona cuando hago esto

```
introducir el código aquí
class obj = new class 
{ /*propiedades.....?*/       }
```

como se llamaría esa operación o declaración  o q es lo exactamente estoy haciendo... al instanciar la clase y utilizar las llaves {}
¿ podria declarar nuevas  propiedades para el  objecto cuando las meto dentro de las llaves 
{} o solamente  darles valores a la propiedades ? () y {}¿al utilisar {} como se llamaria?
posdata : El código del ejemplo funciona correctamente
.net 4.6

Comment: pero este codigo no funciona no?

Comment: Hola quizá lo que buscas son construstores de instancias ... espero esto ayude   https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/instance-constructors

Comment: No se si entiendo muy bien. Te refieres a un [inicializador de objeto](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer)?

Comment: Que version de .net estas usando? Ahora que lo miro mejor, ese código no debería compilar ni siquiera...

Comment: Vale, 4.6. Ese código no puede compilar de ninguna manera, no es posible definir una clase dentro de un método

Comment: Ahhh..ahora cambia mucho la cosa. Es entonces como te dije en mi comentario anterior, un [inicializador de objeto](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer)

Comment: gracias si tienes razón es un inicializador de objetos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuando  **instancias** y das valores con {} solo ingresas cada una de las propiedades

```
var p = new Persona
  {
     Nombre = "Harry",
     edad = 20
  };
```

y cuando lo haces con parentesis hace la misma funcion sin tener que indicar la propiedad si no el orden de las propiedades

```
var p = new Person("Harry"); //aca lo toma como si fuera parametro
```

Creo que eso despeja un poco tu duda  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740658/whats-the-difference-between-an-object-initializer-and-a-constructor

Comment: gracias por el link solucionaste mi duda

Comment: Añadir que para que funcione _con paréntesis_, debe definirse un constructor que reciba esos parámetros.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class obj= new class
{
    I = 1234,
    Ia = "string text"


};
Console.WriteLine(obj.Ia);// output "string text"
Console.ReadLine();
```

}
solo tenias que poner la clase con el modificador de acceso public y usar el nombre con el cual instaseaste el objeto

Answer (score 0):

Tratando de responder a tu pregunta la respuesta es **NO** no puedes agregar nuevas propiedades a un objeto de una clase definida cuando inicias una instancia de ese objeto, para ello tendrías que crear una clase que se extienda de otra clase para que herede las propiedades y ahora si puedas crear nuevas propiedades, para ser más claro, es cómo crear un objeto de la clase Carro sabemos que tiene cuatro ruedas y se queremos añadir otra propiedad a un objeto de esa clase que por ejemplo tenga seis ruedas no lo podemos definir cómo un carro, lo tendríamos que definir cómo otro objeto y puede que herede algunas características de la clase carro.